# How to handle optional parameter + optional return value

Tags: c++, optional-parameters

Problem is as follows: I have a class which encapsulates some sort of container (i.e. a map) which I can query by an object ID. The class also encapsulates a 2nd container which holds additional data (i.e. matrices) belonging to the objects.
The client of my class should have the possibility to query objects and decide on wheter or not he also wants to have the additional data returned, i.e. in this way:

```
ObjectData objData;
Object obj = myClass.getObject(objectID, &objData);
```

However if the client requests the additional data but the object he queries doesn't have additional data linked to it, then the client should be able to tell this. I.e. if my function works like this:

```
Object MyClass::getObject(ObjectID oID, ObjectData* objData)
{
    // ...
    if(objData && this->hasObjectData(oID))
      objData = this->getObjectData(oID);
}
```

and the client calls it in the above way, the getObject function recognizes that the object queried doesn't have additional data with it and will leave the passed objData pointer untouched. The client then finds himself with a default constructed ObjectData object and doesn't know whether it was default constructed or returned by the getObject function as a parameter return value.

On top off my head I can only think of more or less ugly solutions like allocating the data on the heap so that the user can get back nullpointers or somehow add a flag to the function call. Probably a better design would then be to query objectData completely separately but the above would be nice and easy so I wonder if there's an elegant solution to still do it in this way.

Comment: How about using [Boost Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)?

Comment: I don't think the heap allocation / null pointer solution is particularly ugly. You could maybe use smart pointers to make it safer. In the end, I would prefer your second solution though. You could also alter `getObjectData` to take a reference to `ObjectData` and return a bool stating whether data was written or not. This is a little more compact.

Comment: I don't think your code, as written, does what you want it to do. Do you want to provide a copy of any additional data, or a pointer? Assuming you want a copy, it should probably read `*objData = this->getObjectData(oID);` If you want to provide a pointer you need to pass something like `ObjectData*&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getObject(objectID, &objData);
```

By using `getObject` this way you are giving it two responsibilities. First is to get the object ready and second to check if it's possible to load it with additional information. I would suggest divide this into two parts (methods).

```
obj = getObject(objectID);  // get the object based on definite 
                            // info i.e 1st container.
if(obj.isMatrixValid)
    obj.setMatrixData();
```

So, here you separated the responsibilities into two methods. However, one drawback is that you have to remember updating the `object` after creating.

Answer (score 0):

> Probably a better design would then be to query objectData completely separately

**Yes.**

`getObject` has too many responsibilities.

> but the above would be nice and easy

If the client doesn't actually care about the additional object data then this is nicer and easier:

```
Object obj = myClass.getObject(objectID)
```

Then for the separate query for objectData you have a few options. You could force the client to check if you have objectData before querying:

```
if (myClass.hasObjectData()) {
    ObjectData data = myClass.getObjectData();
}
```

Or you could return a pointer. If the client doesn't need to own the `ObjectData` you can just return a raw pointer. If the client needs to own the `ObjectData` I don't think there is anything ugly about allocating on the heap and returning a smart pointer:

```
std::unique_ptr<ObjectData> data = myClass.getObjectData();
if (data) {
    // do something with data...
}
```

Or in a similar way you could use [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).

You might also consider the [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) and return a `NullObjectData` object if there is no additional objectData.